# SDL2 не включает в себя SDL_SCANCODE_ENTER

Tags: c++, клавиатура, sdl2

Необходимо сделать ввод числа с клавиатуры в графическом окне SDL2.
Проблема в том, что я не нашел в макросах SDL2 код клавиши ENTER, что необходимо для завершения ввода. Есть только `SDL_SCANCODE_KP_ENTER`, но так код реагирует только на нажатие ENTER на цифровой клавиатуре, на нажатие основной ENTER не реагирует. Пробовал вместо макросов вставить код клавиши, найденный в интернете, но он не подходил. То есть:

```
while(!key[28]){
...
}
```

Коды 13 и 90 также не подходили.

Как фиксировать нажатие ENTER с помощью SDL_SCANCODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно коды нажатых клавиш стоит получать из событий. Там для клавиши Enter есть `SDLK_RETURN` (на основном блоке клавиш), `SDLK_RETURN2`. Ну или соответствующие `SDL_SCANCODE_`.